# Who changed $i$ to $j$ in electronics?

Tags: notation, electricity

In electronics, $j$ is used for a square root of $-1$, because $I$ is current. Who introduced this and when? And was it really necessary, given that (at least now) current's symbol is capitalised? Perhaps it wasn't at the time, but [as best I can tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Symbol) Ampère didn't use lower case.

Comment: Current in electronics certainly is represented by a small italic i today, particularly for small signal analysis, where complex arithmetic is used extensively! But as for when that started, I couldnt tell you.

Comment: @SamGallagher I was only ever taught to use $I$, but I can understand why a field called "small signal analysis" would use $i$, because it's probably focused on perturbations to background electromagnetism.

Comment: Its a simplified model for circuit analysis, where changes are assumed very small in active (e.g. transistor, op amp, etc) circuits. All "small signal" voltages and currents are represented by lower-case v and i.

Comment: Note that *i* refers to $\sqrt{-1}$  while **i** is often the unit vector in the x-axis.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, but I don't think that concern motivated Steinmetz.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: The unit vector would normally be $\hat{\textbf{i}}$, not just $i$.

Comment: @BenCrowell True that :-) .  I should pay more attention to my Markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol *i* is still used in mathematics; *j* is an invention of an electrical engineers, usually attributed to Charles P. Steinmetz. See for example
[Introduction of $\imath$ and $\jmath$ notations for the imaginary unit](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/introduction-of-imath-and-jmath-notations-for-the-imaginary-unit)

As to why *j* was chosen, the following is quoted from a 1921 book, "Tables of Complex Hyperbolic and Circular Functions" by Arthur Edwin Kennelly. I am sure older ones will also explain the same.

[image: Book image]

My feeling is that since *j* was chosen by a German-born American (Steinmetz), it may be possible to attribute the similarity of *i* and *j* in German e.g. Iodine (symbol I) is Jod (symbol J) in German. However the letter *i* was also introduced by Gauss, who happened to be German, but at that time, Latin was the language of science. This is just my pure speculation.